# yq replace value in manifest yaml

Tags: yq

I have a k8s manifest file for loadbalancer below and cannot for the life of me get the $ipaddress be replaced with value, I have got to to overwrite whole file or part of or even just leave blank. How can I replace only the $ipaddress like in below

Tried as example 2 below:

> ```
> yq e '.spec|=select(.loadBalancerIP) .ports.port = "172.16.87.98"' manifest.yaml
> yq e -i '(.spec|=select(.loadBalancerIP.$ipaddress) = "172.16.87.98"' manifest.yaml
> ```

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: my-lb-cluster
    spec:
      loadBalancerIP: $ipaddress
      ports:
        - name: ssl
          port: 8080
      selector:
        role: webserver
      sessionAffinity: None
      type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Not sure which tag you wanted, but doesn't seem to be related to [tag:jquery]

Comment: Why the `jq` tag?

Comment: apologies, trying to remove , added by mistake

Comment: Are there multiple entrys in the yaml?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the YAML is as simple as in your question, you can use:

```
yq e -i '.spec.loadBalancerIP = "172.16.87.98"' manifest.yaml
```

...to update `manifest.yaml` and set `.loadBalancerIP` inside `.spec` to `"172.16.87.98"`.

Comment: ah dude, thanks I was over complicating this thinking i needed a select to find this

Comment: latest version of yq from 4.18.1 sets eval/e to the default command, so we can remove it altogether. `yq -i '.spec.loadBalancerIP = "172.16.87.98"' manifest.yaml`

Answer (score 8):

I know it's late but this can help if you want to pass the value from a variable.

```
export LB_IP=1.1.1.1

yq e -i '.spec.loadBalancerIP= env(LB_IP)' manifest.yaml
```

Comment: Late but useful!